# How to use JS TypedArray as Rust BufRead/Read without memory copying?

Tags: rust, typed-arrays, wasm-bindgen

I need `Uint8Array` in the form of [`BufRead`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/io/trait.BufRead.html) or [`Read`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/trait.Read.html).

I could just copy the whole memory using something like [`to_vec`](https://docs.rs/js-sys/latest/js_sys/struct.Uint8Array.html#method.to_vec) and construct some type of `BufRead`/`Read` but I don't want to because the array I'm dealing with can be huge (50~100mb)

I think in order to do that I have to get the address to the mutable continuous memory block, probably in type of `*mut [u8]`. (I'm not familiar with Rust yet so the syntax might not be right but hope you get the idea).
But I can't find the suitable method from [`Uint8Array` doc](https://docs.rs/js-sys/latest/js_sys/struct.Uint8Array.html).

Is it possible? If so, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to copy the data. WebAssembly does not directly have access to memory in the JavaScript environment and must be copied over. Using `to_vec` is the way to go.